# Right way to write JSON deserializer in Spring or extend it

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to write a custom JSON deserializer in Spring. I want to use default serializer for most part of fields and use a custom deserializer for few properties. Is it possible?
I am trying this way because, most part of properties are values, so for these I can let Jackson use default deserializer; but few properties are references, so in the custom deserializer I have to query a database for reference name and get reference value from database.

I'll show some code if needed.

Comment: To clarify, how is it to be determined whether custom processing is to be used: by field name (effectively), or by field type?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this comment @ProgrammerBruce .. I think, by field type..

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I've searched a lot and the best way I've found so far is on this [article](https://www.sghill.net/how-do-i-write-a-jackson-json-serializer-deserializer.html):

**Class to serialize**

```
package net.sghill.example;

import net.sghill.example.UserDeserializer
import net.sghill.example.UserSerializer
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;

@JsonDeserialize(using = UserDeserializer.class)
public class User {
    private ObjectId id;
    private String   username;
    private String   password;

    public User(ObjectId id, String username, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public ObjectId getId()       { return id; }
    public String   getUsername() { return username; }
    public String   getPassword() { return password; }
}
```

**Deserializer class**

```
package net.sghill.example;

import net.sghill.example.User;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.ObjectCodec;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationContext;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class UserDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<User> {

    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        return new User(null, node.get("username").getTextValue(), node.get("password").getTextValue());
    }
}
```

Edit:
Alternatively you can look at [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) which uses new versions of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer.

Comment: Hey, that's my article! Glad you found it helpful :)

Comment: In new versions of jackson in `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer` class use `asText()` instead of `getTextValue()` to get the text. Thanks!! +1 `:)`

Comment: But If it is not my custom class

Comment: I've got NPE on "oc.readTree" with that approach. Does anybody know how to handle it?

Comment: Jackson now recommends extending the `StdDeserializer<Foo>` class FYI.

Comment: This worked for me. My use case was to use custom logic for just one field. Is there any way to do that? The approach in question requires writing logic for all the member variables.

Answer (score 11):

I was trying to `@Autowire` a Spring-managed service into my `Deserializer`. Somebody tipped me off to Jackson using the `new` operator when invoking the serializers/deserializers. This meant no auto-wiring of Jackson's instance of my `Deserializer`. Here's how I was able to `@Autowire` my service class into my `Deserializer`:

**context.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
      <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper" />
    </bean>
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc>
<bean id="objectMapper" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
    <!-- Add deserializers that require autowiring -->
    <property name="deserializersByType">
        <map key-type="java.lang.Class">
            <entry key="com.acme.Anchor">
                <bean class="com.acme.AnchorDeserializer" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now that my `Deserializer` is a Spring-managed bean, auto-wiring works!

**AnchorDeserializer.java**

```
public class AnchorDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Anchor> {
    @Autowired
    private AnchorService anchorService;
    public Anchor deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
             throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

**AnchorService.java**

```
@Service
public class AnchorService {}
```

---

**Update**: While my original answer worked for me back when I wrote this, @xi.lin's response is exactly what is needed. Nice find!

Comment: Your solution not helped to me. I solved this problem using  **[SpringBeanAutowiringSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html)**.

Comment: I think you can also see this [refer](http://www.runningasroot.com/blog/2012/05/02/autowiring-jackson-deserializers-in-spring/) that use `HandlerInstantiator` to do this.

Comment: It's interesting that this approach works for some and not for others. The approach used by @PeterJurkovič did not work for me, but this one does.

Comment: Perhaps it's been fixed in later versions. I don't remember which Spring version I was using when I wrote this, but that would have been very important to note.

Comment: If you want to use it without XML config just look on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48421764/325868)

Answer (score 1):

With Spring MVC 4.2.1.RELEASE, you need to use the new Jackson2 dependencies as below for the Deserializer to work.

Dont use this

```
<dependency>  
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>  
            <version>1.9.12</version>  
        </dependency>
```

Use this instead.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer` and  `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize` for the deserialization and not the classes from `org.codehaus.jackson`

Answer (score 0):

1. If you wanna override default deserialiser for specific properties, you can mark the properties and the deserialiser you want to use, eg:

--

```
// root json object
public class Example {
  private String name;
  private int value;
  // You will implement your own deserilizer/Serializer for the field below//
  @JsonSerialize(converter = AddressSerializer.class)
  @JsonDeserialize(converter = AddressDeserializer.class)
  private String address;
}
```

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson_annotations/jackson_annotations_jsondeserialize.htm) is a complete example.

2. If you want to use non spring managed object mapper in Spring application context and configure the serialisers/deserialisers to use spring managed services to query the database, that can be achieved by telling Jackson to use `Spring Handler instantiator` to create instances of Deserialisers/Serialisers.

In your application context config, create `ObjectMapper` bean with `SpringHandlerInstantiator` eg:

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Bean    
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.handlerInstantiator(handlerInstantiator());
    // add additional configs, etc.. here if needed
    return builder.build();
}

@Bean
public HandlerInstantiator handlerInstantiator(){
    return new SpringHandlerInstantiator(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
}
```

Then you can @Autowire above objectMapper to deserialise jsons:

```
@Autowired
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public Something readSomething(...){
    ...
    Something st = objectMapper.readValue(json, Something.class);
    ...
    return st;
}
```

Regardless of the deserialiser you want to use, ie: field or class, you can use spring context in the deserialiser, meaning that you can @Autowire your services or any spring bean managed by the same `ApplicationContext` into it.

```
public class MyCustomDeserialiser extends ..{
      
    @Autowired;
    MyService service;

    @AutoWired
    SomeProperties properties;

    @Override
    public MyValue deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    ....
    }
    ...
}
```

Additionally, you can find an example of Jackson deserialiser [here](https://dzone.com/articles/custom-json-deserialization-with-jackson).