# jackson - ignoring case in snake case keys

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have a requirement to receive JSON with keys that contain underscore and even ignore the case in words. For e.g. Device_control_API, device_control_API, Device_Control_API, device_control_aPI etc all should map to same property.

Now I know that I can create multiple setter methods using @JsonSetter with all combinations possible, but I don't think that will be good.

I have seen other questions which suggest using `mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true)` 
for ObjectMapper object to ignore case, but I can't do that because I am using spring-boot and want my REST API to get payload in the form POJO object.

Is there any annotation or some way to do so

Please help !!!

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can use the `MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES` as annotation. Got the following information from [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Mapper-Features)

> **Jackson on/off features: MapperFeature**
>
> Jackson defines a set of per-mapper configuration, which can ONLY be
>   defined before using ObjectMapper -- meaning that these settings can
>   not be changed on-the-fly, on per-request basis. They configure
>   fundamental POJO introspection details, and resulting built objects
>   (serializers, deserializers, related) are heavily cached. If you need
>   differing settings for these, **you have to use separate ObjectMapper
>   instances.**

And the `MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES` is one of the configuration.

---

But maybe a custom deserialization class could help you. There are many tutorials and questions on Stackoverflow.

I found some:

- [Jackson: using @JsonSerialize (or @JsonDeserialize) annotation to register a custom serializer (or deserializer)](http://www.davismol.net/2015/06/05/jackson-using-jsonserialize-or-jsondeserialize-annotation-to-register-a-custom-serializer-or-deserializer/)
- [Right way to write JSON deserializer in Spring or extend it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376304/right-way-to-write-json-deserializer-in-spring-or-extend-it)

Answer (score 1):

There is also this property:

`spring.jackson.mapper.accept_case_insensitive_properties=true`