# How to customize Jackson ObjectMapper with Spring application.properties?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I want to enable the following jackson mapper feature:
`MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES`

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html:

Could be configured in `application.properties` as follows:
`spring.jackson.mapper.accept_case_insensitive_properties=true`

But:

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public void test(@Valid TestReq req) {

    }
}

public class TestReq {
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
}
```

Usage:

```
localhost:8080/test?name=test //works
localhost:8080/test?Name=test //fails with 'name may not be blank'
```

So, the case insensitive property is not taken into account. But why?

By the way: even using `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` explicit does not work:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer initJackson() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer c = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
            builder.featuresToEnable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES);
        }
    };

    return c;
}
```

spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE

Comment: Where are you creating the ObjectMapper instance, in a java class file or in the spring config?

Comment: It is automatically created by `spring-boot` or `spring-mvc`, and should thereby use the configuration properties during initialization.

Comment: I think you need to change your tags to add spring-boot

Comment: In the URL you are passing name as query string. Query strings are case sensitive, where as URL domain name isn't.

Comment: That's exactly what the `MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES` feature is for: making query strings behave case insensitive. But somehow it does not work even though the feature exists.

Comment: Doest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351964/jackson-ignoring-case-in-snake-case-keys) help you in any way?

Comment: No, it just states that the feature exists, which I'm aware of.

Comment: Even though I don't configure `application.properties file`, it also works well in my environment. I annotated `TestReq` class with @Data from `lombok`.

Comment: Which version of spring are you using? I'm on `1.5.3`.

Comment: The version is v1.5.1.RELEASE.

Comment: What you are trying is data binding which does nothing with Jackson. You are passing URL parameters whereas the Jackson serializer/mapper will only be active for response bodies NOT parameters.

Comment: @M.Deinum is there a way to achieve the same effect of `ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES` and `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` on URL parameters?

Comment: Not an easy one that I'm aware of. You could create a filter which would wrap the request and uses a `CaseInsensitiveMap` to store/retrieve the request params. You would have to do it yourself, as stated data binding doesn't do anything with Jackson.

Comment: I'm able to replicate on `1.5.3.RELEASE` version.

Comment: @M.Deinum Indeed I tested `@PostMapping` with `@RequestBody` successfully

Comment: Did you tried `spring.jackson.mapper.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES=true` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: it is not possible.

The `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` affects the JSON POST requests only. It has no effect on the get query binding.

Answer (score 4):

According to [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) you can customize it.

I fix this problem by set my application.yml like this(spring 2.0):

```
 spring:
  jackson:
    mapper:
      ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES: true
```

Did you tried change your setting `accept_case_insensitive_properties` to UPPER CASE？

Also you can keep output to Upper Case by setting like this:

```
  jackson:
    mapper:
      ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES: true
    property-naming-strategy: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy.PascalCaseStrategy
```

Note that PascalCaseStrategy was deprecated now, but still working.

Comment: Current version of spring/spring-boot uses `spring.jackson.mapper.accept-case-insensitive-properties=true` (hyphens not underscores for the property name; not sure if case-sensitive or not).